# iPhone How to get image back from NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsdate, uiimagejpegrepresentation

In my iPhone App I am storing image into `NSData` by

```
UIImage *image =imageView.image;

NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

But How to get back "image" from  "`NSData`"  and I can display it again into in to `UIImageView`.

Please Help and Suggest,
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

have you tried `+[UIImage imageWithData:]`?

Comment: + [UIImage imageWithData:] ... it's a class method.

Answer (score 7):

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
[yourImageView setImage:img];
```