# How to receive bufferedimage from Java server using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, post, bufferedimage, outputstream, java-server

I'm developing an Ipad app. I have to use the POST method to sent request to the Java server, then, the Java server will produce an outputstream of an bufferedimage. How can I receive this bufferedimage using objective-c?

the POST method's code:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:cmdString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"cmd"];
[_request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:paramString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"param"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:_request delegate:self];
```

the Java server's code:

```
    OutputStream os=http.getResponseBody();
    String cmd=http.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("cmd");
    int cnt=Integer.valueOf(http.getRequestHeaders().getFirst("param"));
    System.out.println(cmd+"   "+cnt);
    int w,h;
    http.sendResponseHeaders(200,0);
    if(cmd.equals("1"))
    {
        w=512;
        h=512;
        idlmanager idl=new idlmanager();
        idl.createObject();
        byte[] buf=new byte[w*h*3+1];
        JIDLArray idlBuf=new JIDLArray(buf);
        JIDLNumber r=idl.UPDATEIMAGE(idlBuf,new JIDLInteger(1), new JIDLInteger(cnt));
        buf=(byte[]) idlBuf.arrayValue();
        int i,j;
        int[] data =new int[w*h];
        for(i=0;i<w*h;i++)
        {           
            data[i]=((buf[i*3]+256)%256)*256*256+((buf[i*3+1]+256)%256)*256+(buf[i*3+2]+256)%256;
        }

        int[] mask={255*256*256,255*256,255};
        ColorModel cm=new DirectColorModel(24,255*256*256 , 255*256,255);
        SampleModel sm=new SinglePixelPackedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT,w,h,mask);          
        DataBuffer db = new DataBufferInt(data, w*h);
        WritableRaster rast=Raster.createWritableRaster(sm,db, new Point(0,0));

        BufferedImage bufImg= new BufferedImage(cm, rast, false, null);
        ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", os);
    }else if(cmd.equals("2")){....}
```

Comment: Thanks to @Owen 's answer, I can successfully receive the response data now. And I found the right way to display image from this response data from there: [get image back from NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655174/iphone-how-to-get-image-back-from-nsdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a) from NSURLConnection.

```
__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
__autoreleasing NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[responseData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

Assume `savePath` is a NSString contains a valid path.

if you want to use [connectionWithRequest:delegate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest%3adelegate%3a) as mentioned in your code, you will have to implement the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %d %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [responseData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES]; 
}
```

here responseData is an instance variable declared with:

```
NSMutableData *responseData;
```

and your class must conforms the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocols.

Comment: `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    [_responseData writeToFile:@"~/Documents/responseData.txt" atomically:YES];
}`
Sorry, this is the code I'm using now. It prints `(null)`, which means there is no data received? and there is no file saved. Is the path I used a valid one? Cheers

Comment: oh, I wanted to save the file on my Mac, but I don't think it's permitted. Could u plz give me a valid path example? That would be helpful. @Owen

Comment: try the Application Support folder: `NSString *savePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourAppName"];`